# remove chapter margin

Tags: color, margins, chapterthumb

I'm using this ChapterFrame: Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin

YOU SHOULD COMPILE THREE TIMES BEFORE TO SEE THE MARGINS !

I add the chapter frame under the first three chapters... with \ChapFrame how you can see!

the problem is that in the fourth chapter I didn't add anything like /chapframe, but it has still the same margin of the previous one!! I would like to stop with the chapter margin for the fourth chapter! how can I do that?

```
\documentclass[headsepline,BCOR=10mm,11pt,twoside,openright,cleardoublepage=empty,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm,paperheight=24cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,inner=2.0cm,outer=1.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=1,
  contents={}
]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[numbers,comma,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[format=plain,singlelinecheck=false,font={footnotesize,sl},labelfont=bf]{caption}

%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%\linespread{1.0}
\usepackage[english,dutch,UKenglish]{babel}
%\epstopdfsetup{update} % only regenerate pdf files when eps file is newer
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\definecolorseries{chcolor}{rgb}{grad}[rgb]{.95,.85,.55}{3,11,17}
\resetcolorseries{chcolor}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{color}

\pagestyle{plain}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame{%
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifodd\value{page}
      \backgroundsetup{contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
          \node[
            fill=\BoxColor,
            inner sep=0pt,
            rectangle,
            text width=1cm,
            text height=4cm,
            align=center,
            anchor=north east
          ] 
          at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
          {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.6cm}\parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
              \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }  
    \else
      \backgroundsetup{contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[
          fill=\BoxColor,
          inner sep=0pt,
          rectangle,
          text width=1cm,
          text height=4cm,
          align=center,
          anchor=north west
        ] 
        at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
        {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.6cm}\parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
            \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }  
    \fi
  \BgMaterial}%
  \stepcounter{chapshift}%
}

% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}} 

\begin{document}

\chapter[intro]{Introduction}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Discussion}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{prova}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With package `scrlayer-scrpage` and package `chapterthumb` (from http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/info/examples/KOMA-Script-6/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty or https://komascript.de/files/KOMA-Script-6-Buch-Beispielcode.zip) you can add the chapter frames to the pagestyle. Then you have to compile only once.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}% http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/KOMA-Script-6/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty

\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\value{chapterthumb} blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

\renewcommand*\firstchapterthumbskip{0pt}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbheight{1cm}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbwidth{4cm}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbformat{%
  \centering
  \parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{\raggedright\leftmark}%
}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbboxcolor{\BoxColor}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbcolor{black}
\setkomafont{chapterthumb}{\scshape}

\DeclareNewLayer[
clone=chapterthumb,
evenpage,
leftmargin,
width=\chapterthumbheight
]{chapterthumb.even}

\newcommand*\enableChapterFrame{%
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}{}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}}%
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb.even}{}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb.even}}%
}
\newcommand*\disableChapterFrame{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb,chapterthumb.even}%
}

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.~}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\enableChapterFrame
\chapter[intro]{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[1-7]
\chapter{Discussion}
\lipsum[1-7]

\cleardoublepage
\disableChapterFrame
\chapter{prova}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

This would also work with standard class `book`, if you replace

```
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.~}
```

by

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}
```

---

With **KOMA-Script Version 3.27** and a KOMA-Script class you can also use a do-hook to autoremove the layers from the page styles when a new chapter starts:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}[2019/10/12]% needs version 3.27 or newer
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}

\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\value{chapterthumb} blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

\renewcommand*\firstchapterthumbskip{0pt}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbheight{1cm}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbwidth{4cm}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbformat{%
  \centering
  \parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{\raggedright\leftmark}%
}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbboxcolor{\BoxColor}
\renewcommand*\chapterthumbcolor{black}
\setkomafont{chapterthumb}{\scshape}

\DeclareNewLayer[
clone=chapterthumb,
evenpage,
leftmargin,
width=\chapterthumbheight
]{chapterthumb.even}

\newcommand*\ChapterFrame{%
  \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb,chapterthumb.even}%
}

\newcommand*\disableChapterFrame[1]{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb,chapterthumb.even}%
}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit/chapter}{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb,chapterthumb.even}%
}

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter.~}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\chapter[intro]{Introduction}\ChapterFrame
\lipsum[1-7]
\chapter{Results}\ChapterFrame
\lipsum[1-7]
\chapter{Discussion}\ChapterFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{prova}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Result for both examples:

[image]

Comment: the packages are not working :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `\ChapFrame` macro spans over **every pages** as specified by `\AddEverypageHook`.

One dirty solution is to conditionally enable/disable it, by adding an argument to this command:

```
% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame[1]{%
 \ifodd#1
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifodd\value{page}
      \backgroundsetup{contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
          \node[
            fill=\BoxColor,
            inner sep=0pt,
            rectangle,
            text width=1cm,
            text height=4cm,
            align=center,
            anchor=north east
          ] 
          at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
          {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.6cm}\parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
              \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }  
    \else
      \backgroundsetup{contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[
          fill=\BoxColor,
          inner sep=0pt,
          rectangle,
          text width=1cm,
          text height=4cm,
          align=center,
          anchor=north west
        ] 
        at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
        {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.6cm}\parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
            \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }  
    \fi
  \BgMaterial}%
  \stepcounter{chapshift}%
 \else
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifodd\value{page}
      \backgroundsetup{contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
          \node[
            draw=white,
            fill=white,
            inner sep=0pt,
            rectangle,
            text width=1cm,
            text height=4cm,
            align=center,
            anchor=north east
          ] 
          at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
          {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.6cm}\parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
              \raggedright\textcolor{white}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }  
    \else
      \backgroundsetup{contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[
          draw=white,
          fill=white,
          inner sep=0pt,
%          rectangle,
          text width=1cm,
          text height=4cm,
          align=center,
          anchor=north west
        ] 
        at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
        {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.6cm}\parbox[c][0.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
            \raggedright\textcolor{white}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }  
    \fi
  \BgMaterial}%
  \stepcounter{chapshift}%
 \fi
}
```

Use `\ChapFrame{1}` to enable, `\ChapFrame{0}` to disbale.

```
% Previous tex header
\chapter[intro]{Introduction}
\ChapFrame{1}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\ChapFrame{1}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Discussion}
\ChapFrame{1}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{prova}
\ChapFrame{0}
\lipsum[1-7]
```

A bit more `tikz` work is needed to make this solution proper.

**EDIT** the additional `tikz` required to hide the residual rectangles was to display them in white.

Yet, I still qualify my answer as a dirty patch rather than a "TeX"y solution...

Comment: this is a smart method! but when I run it I can still see the white box! do you think is possible tell to the system to fill with nothing!!?!?!

Comment: Agreed, that's why I was saying: "A bit more `tikz` work is needed to make this solution proper". I've edited my answer to add the bit more work, should be working right now.